# How to store user activities to database using sessions : Codeigniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session

I have this site http://mxcounters.com/traffictack/

Users come to site register and logged in. After login they search their domain for some seo reviews. Now all I want to store the each user search into database separately. Then I will show the searched domain by each user to their account page.

I have tried some last activity method to store in database but it is not as much useful please help me on this:

```
       $time_since = now() - $this->session->userdata('last_activity');
       $interval = 300;
       // Do nothing if last activity is recent
       if ($time_since < $interval) return;
       // Update database
       $updated = $this->db
       ->set('last_activity', now())
       ->where('id', $user_id)
       ->update('users');
```

Comment: you want store time of user activities?? alone with where they visited ??

Comment: User search for site reviews from their account. so each user search will be stored to corresponding user data in database.

Comment: search means any search filed input??

Comment: yes there is a form  check this link" http://mxcounters.com/traffictack/woorank/

Are you on skype?

Comment: I have send request there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**In conteroller**

```
$userId = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
if(empty($userId)){
    redirect('login'); # this for user not logged
}
else{
    $search  = $this->input->post('domain');

    $resut = $this->method_name->serach_domain($userId, $search);
    if(!empty($resut)){

        #have data. if user come here set another methods for Insert data
        $this->model_name->insert_search_result(($userId, $search);

    }
    else{

        # nodata
        echo "No result found"
    }

}
```

**In Model**

```
function insert_search_result(($userId, $search){

    $data = array(
       'user_id' => $userID ,
       'search' => $search,
       'timestamp' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );

    $this->db->insert('mytable', $data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. i am close to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert each search you can use:

First create a table in which the records are stored.

```
CREATE TABLE `usersearchs` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`search` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
INDEX `id` (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

In this table the timestamp is automaticly added to the entries.

then use a insert query on each search:

```
INSERT INTO usersearch (user_id, search) VALUES ($user_id, $search_string);
```

If you only want to update the last_activity column:

Alter your table that after every table update the last_activity is updated and use a second column e.g. named searchString to contain the last searched item.

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
CHANGE COLUMN `last_activity` `last_activity` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
ADD COLUMN `searchString` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL AFTER;
```

Then use a query on each search:

```
UPDATE users SET searchString = `$searchstring` WHERE id = $userID
```

Please use right escaping when using databases (PDO prepared statements are a good option)